# Scrape web content using bs4?

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
https://www.linkedin.com/learning/topics/business
```

This is url which I used to scrape the required content like Windows Quick Tips

```
   source=urllib.request.urlopen
           ("https://www.linkedin.com/learning/topics/business")
   source=source.read()
   soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
   f=soup.body
   r=soup.find_all('div')
   for x in r:
       d=x.find('main')
```

I want  to **scrape** the content like Windows Quick Tips in webpage

Comment: LinkedIn Learning pages are dynamic, means It will load content as you scroll but you are scrapping with `urllib` and `bs4` you won't get full content. I'll suggest use some browser automation tools like `selenium`. Just to get Title of topics, understand the DOM, how they are being structured.

Comment: Is there any possible chances to extract required output using bs4